# Warped Rectangular panel with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, panel

So I was working on an application and was wondering how I can "warp" a rectangular panel and its contents into the following kind of shape at "Load" event:

[image: Warped Rectangle]

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are working with Windows Forms you can't do it.
What you can do is to handle the paint event of the panel and trying to manually draw a border that looks like the one you want. See [Control.Paint Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint?view=netframework-4.0) for more information.

Or (this is the easy way) you can simply fill the panel background with an image.
Use `BackgroundImage` property of the panel to set an image file and set `BackgroundImageLayout` to Stretch so your image will cover the entire area of the panel.

Comment: Should I be working with something other than forms to do this easily?

Comment: Also I need it so that the content follows the upper and lower edges of the curve

Comment: For what I know is not possible unless you code a layout engine for your panel

Comment: how will a layout engine allow me to do that?

Comment: You have to code the rules to set the position (x,y) of the items you add to the panel

Comment: But does it make the controls curve along the edges?

Comment: Do you also want to curve the controls inside the panel?

Comment: Yup, I wanna curve everything I put in that panel

Comment: Then draw that everything curved.